# Draw a 4x4 Grid Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, stddraw

I am trying to draw a 4x4 grid using a 2D array. When I run the code, I only draw a square in the lower left corner. I think the issue might be with my y-coordinate but I am not completely sure.

```
StdDraw.setScale(0,4);

int[][] grid = new int[4][4];

for (int x = 0; x < grid.length; x++)
{
  for (int y = 0; y < grid[0].length; y++)
  {
    StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLUE);
    StdDraw.filledSquare(grid[x][y], grid[x+1][y+1], 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: You are drawing all 16 points at the same location of `(0,0)` because `new int[4][4]` makes an array of all zeros.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't this just because your multidimensional grid array is all 0's due to default initialization? You are drawing four squares at coord 0,0 with size 1.

Comment: Is this an answer or a question?

Comment: I'd say it's an answer, @IngoBürk. Some trivial grammar makes it look like a question, but that doesn't matter in the long run as long as it could solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work:

```
StdDraw.setScale(0,4);

int[][] grid = new int [4][4];

for (int x = 0; x < grid.length; x++)
{
  for (int y = 0; y < grid.length; y++)
  {
    grid[x][y] = 255;
  }
}

for (int x = 0; x < grid.length; x++)
{
  for (int y = 0; y <grid.length; y++)
  {
    StdDraw.square(x, y, 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Good work, inda1. If Barry's answer helped you solve your problem (I think it did), consider marking his answer as correct, or upvote it or something.